# Why is my window.scroll function firing twice ONLY when declaring a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this window scroll function to query more results when a user scrolls to the bottom of a div. The start is used to increment the query so I dont duplicate results. It keeps firing twice for some reason and I cant figure out why `start=start+4;` is causing it to. If I remove the line, or simply change it to something that breaks it, it fires once. But ran like this, it fires twice. Can someone figure out why this is happening?

```
var limit = 4;
var start = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.tasks-column').on("scroll", function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >=$(this)[0].scrollHeight){
          alert("run");
          start=start+4;
          filter_data(start,limit);
} 
}); 
});
```

**EDIT**
I tested out "start" with other numbers, and there seems to be a problem once I get over the increment of 4. Before that there are no problems

Comment: I can't seem to understand your code. why did you do `$(this)[0]`?

Comment: How does `start` factor into this? What does `filter_data` do ? But scroll events can queue up and some may fulfill the condition, firing multiple times.

Comment: honestly, i found the example on another SO post. so i basically just copied the window function and put in my own div. I dont know why that person used `$(this)[0]` but if i remove the `[0]` it stops working... the start is for a query string, it for the `LIMIT 0,4`. So when it runs to the bottom it does 0+4. meaning... `LIMIT 4,4` which loads 4 more results from the DB. the filter_data just gets the results based on the filters that are selected

Comment: The `[0]` returns the first html [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) in the jQuery collection. As the collection is created in place with just one element, `$(this)[0]` and `this` are equivalent. Except in performance.

Comment: thanks, which is more efficient?

Comment: The native element `this`, as you don't have to create the colection.

Comment: @msg That's what I would assume but how sure are we that there's actually a list of Nodes there? That's where my confusion is... like `.tasks-column` that sounds like just one column if you read that class

Comment: @MosiaThabo If there's an event handler executing, there's an element receiving the action. Even if `.task-column` is a collection, `this` is only one element in that collection.